# Ler XML dentro de Textarea com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma página HTML normal 
e dentro dela tenho um textearea com um XML da mesma página.

Como da pra ver na imagem abaixo o XML esta dentro de um textearea. 
Preciso ler e usar os dados dele com Jquery ou JS.

Minha url fica assim http://meusite.com/pagina

[image: Print]

o Load do Jquery pode me ajudar ? 
Qual seria outra alternativa melhor para ler e usar os dados deste textarea ?

Já busquei em tudo, em várias línguas e não consegui. 
Se você sabe um tutorial, ou algo que o valha deixe o link.

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que fique assim:

Fonte: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
var xml = $('textAreaSelector').val(),
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $imagem = $xml.find( "imagem" );
```

Comment: Desculpa, mas sou totalmente noob em Jquery e JS

Como faço para receber a URL e depois fazer o que vc disse ?

Comment: Você quer capturar essas informações de um outro site? Não entendi direito o que vc precisa.

Comment: Desculpe, não fui claro.

Essas informações estão no meu site.

Quero por a parte do XML em um APP (android ) com jquery mobile.

Já usei o Load do Jquery (funciona, mas preciso manipular + os dados), por isso o XML que facilitaria muito mais.